# VBA cannot find file while accessing an excel file in share point

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to access an excel file that resides in sharepoint 2010

https://website.com/site/core/Dev/files/testfile.xls

I have a vba code that looks for the excel file under this path and checks if the file is open. While using a share point path I get an error. After i stepped through the code I found that it returns error 52( bad file name).
After some research I observed that if I used a local path on my machine I do not see this error. This specifically happens when I use the path in sharepoint.

Has anyone observed this before ? any suggestions to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Show the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the https: in front of the name so just check for //website.com/site/core/Dev/files/testfile.xls

Comment: I used the actual path for the excel file that was in the properties and this worked.